# vector element-wise product with C++ and STL

Tags: c++, stl

It is not difficult to implement  element-wise product in C++:

```
vector<float> a_array;
vector<float> b_array;
vector<float> c_array;
vector<float> dot_array;
....
for(int i=0; i<a_array.size(); i++)
{
   float temp;
   temp = a_array[i]*b_array[i]*c_array[i];
   dot_array[i] = temp;
}
```

This is a very simple implementation, and I am wondering whether there are more efficient algorithms already available in STL. Thanks!

Comment: This is not dot product.

Comment: You mean the element-wise product of two or more vectors. The dot product (aka scalar or inner product) is `sum(a[i]*b[i])`, which is not what your code does.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the content of the question

Comment: The generalisation of that is really hard to write. `inner_product` will work fine for 2 vectors but won't work for `n` or even `>2`. In `C++11` it is possible to define `n-ary` algorithms that can do what you want.

Comment: Having looked at people's answers I wouldn't say that the STL algorithms are more efficient. They do pretty much the same as you but also include an overhead which hits on the efficiency.

Comment: @DrYap: That entirely depends on how the algorithm is implemented. If it takes advantage of, for example, vectorised arithmetic then it could be much faster than a simple `for` loop. But as always, if efficiency is important, the only reliable way to tell what is faster is to measure it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::transform` can be used to multiply two vectors:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

// Precondition: b.size() >= a.size() && r.size() >= a.size()
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), r.begin(), std::multiplies<float>());
```

There is no similar standard algorithm with more than two input sequences.

Comment: 2 questions: is the product of a[i] and b[i] copied into r[i] --or is it moved? and could one replace r.begin() with a.begin() (overwriting a)?

Comment: The product was never stored anywhere previously, so it was neither copied or moved. And yes, I believe you can set the output to be the same as the input and it will do the transformation in place.

Comment: Since C++14, we can do just `std::multiplies{}`. Or `std::multiplies<>{}` or `std::multiplies()`, or... whatever. The same goes for other similar ones, such as `std::plus`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [std::inner_product](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product).

**Edit** I posted this answer when the question was about dot product. For element-wise product, see the second version of [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Thanks, but here I am interested in dot product.

Comment: @feelfree in this context, inner product and dot product are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `std::vector` class isnt actually a mathematically vector but a dynmaically sized array, a collection. You probably got confused due to its name. Defining a real `vector` class implementing mathematically operations is prefered instead of (mis)using a `std::vector`.